# How can I update a series of tables with values from one table in SAS?

Tags: sas

I'd like to update a series of tables with values from just one table. I'm trying something like this:

```
%let list_counter = 3;

%macro update_list_view;
proc sql;
%do i=1 %to &list_counter;
update temp.rule_list_value_&i a
set attribute_code = (select attribute_code from
                        temp.country b
                        where a.primary_entity_key = b.primary_entity_key);
%end;
quit;

%mend update_list_view;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You will want to add an existential qualifier for the rows that are to be updated.

```
  ...
  where exists ( <sub-select> )
```

In this case, the sub-select can be the same as the `set` assignment `select`.  The update requires the table `temp.country` be unique in `primary_entity_key`.

Example:

```
data have_1 have_2 have_3;
  do key = 1 to 10;
    code = key*2; output have_1;
    code = key*10; output have_2;
    code = 100+key; output have_3;
  end;
run;

* updated code for key to be applied;
data new_codes;
  key = 5; code = 555; output;
  key = 9; code = 999; output;
run;

%macro update_code(base=, n=, data=);
  %local i;

  proc sql;

    %do i = 1 %to &n;

      update &&base.&i as outer
      set code = ( select code from &data as inner
                   where inner.key = outer.key
                 )
      where exists
                 ( select code from &data as inner
                   where inner.key = outer.key
                 )
      ;

    %end;

  quit;

%mend;

%update_code(base=have_, n=3, data=new_codes);

%let syslast=have_1;
```

Will Log

```
NOTE: 2 rows were updated in WORK.HAVE_1.
NOTE: 2 rows were updated in WORK.HAVE_2.
NOTE: 2 rows were updated in WORK.HAVE_3.
```